# Javascript and Typescript: iteration over object with for..of

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, generator, iterable

From [ES6 iteration over object values](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-iteration-over-object-values) I took a way of iteration over object values. Here's my implementation:

```
function* entries (obj): IterableIterator<any> {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        const value = obj[key];
        yield [
            key,
            value,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then I want to use that in `render()` React Component's method:

```
render () {
    const that = this;
    const newVar = (() => {
        const elements = [];
        for (const [key, value] of entries(that.filters)) {
            elements.push(<h2>{JSON.stringify(key)} {JSON.stringify(value)}</h2>);
        }
        return elements;

    })();
    return (
        <section>
            {newVar}
        </section>
    );
}
```

But if I debug this code with .`map` files in Chrome Developer console, `newVar` is an empty array. If I alert `obj` in `entries` generator I got proper object. Am I missing something really simple? Thank you in advance for every answer. I use Typescript with `es5` option and I read that it supports generators: [Generators and Iteration for ES5/ES3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html).

Comment: Btw, you should neither need `that` nor the IIFE.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the `--downlevelIteration` flag as mentioned in the TypeScript docs you linked?

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't :) Thank you so much, I waste few hours before you answered me, please write your post as new answer and I will accept it. I knew it's something stupid simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use Typescript with `es5` option and I read that it supports generators: [Generators and Iteration for ES5/ES3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html).

It also says that you need to use the `--downlevelIteration` flag for that. Otherwise it will still transpile `for … of`-loops into array iteration, which fails on iterables like your generator instance without a `.length` property.